# Change the items on an unpaid Stripe order

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it possible to change the items on an unpaid Stripe order or is that locked in once created?

I'm creating an unpaid placeholder order along with a customer source so that when a user is ready to complete checkout they don't have to wait on multiple API calls when they click the final submit button.

Comment: what you are describing seems to be shopping cart scenarios. The answer is definitely yes. 
Depends on your integration path, Stripe charge and PaymentIntent API is not tied to any items and it only cares the final amount you tell the API to charge. What you could do is to put your order items in Shopping Cart (Session), upon user click the submit button, you would pass the items to your server side, calculate the total amount and then call Stripe API to complete the transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the Orders API (which has since been deprecated), then no once you create the order you can't update the items in it. Instead you should just track the items in your customer's cart yourself and create the Stripe payment when you are ready to initiate the charge.